# Target specific <div> CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got this HTML structure and I want to target `divs` in CSS like this :

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
```

I don't know how to target these divs in CSS, using `nth-child` ?

Comment: div:nth-child(3n);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to change style of every third element.You can do:

```css
div:nth-child(3n+0) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css, as your div sibling styles is applied to multiple of 3.. ie third, sixth, nineth....

```
div:nth-child(3n) {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div{background-color:red;}
div:nth-child(3n){background-color:black;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div>D</div>
<div>E</div>
<div>F</div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->
<div>G</div>
<div>H</div>
<div>I</div> <!-- SPECIFIC STYLE -->

</body>
</html>
```